# Python dividing time intervals into hourly buckets in

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, data-manipulation

I have a dataset as below where each ID can checkin and chekout at any given time and duration

```
            ID  checkin_datetime    checkout_datetime
            4   04-01-2019 13:07    04-01-2019 13:09
            4   04-01-2019 13:09    04-01-2019 13:12
            4   04-01-2019 14:06    04-01-2019 14:07
            4   04-01-2019 14:55    04-01-2019 15:06
            22  04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32
            22  04-01-2019 21:38    04-01-2019 21:42
            25  04-01-2019 23:22    04-02-2019 00:23
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15
```

The Checked in minutes computed from this needs to be divided into into hourly buckets as in the following table so that I can compute the cumulative totals by the hour each Id across hours and days even when the checkin check out is taking place across days.

Help appreciated :)

```
            ID  checkin_datetime    checkout_datetime   day         HR  Minutes
            4   04-01-2019 13:07    04-01-2019 13:09    04-01-2019  13  2
            4   04-01-2019 13:09    04-01-2019 13:12    04-01-2019  13  3
            4   04-01-2019 14:06    04-01-2019 14:07    04-01-2019  14  1
            4   04-01-2019 14:55    04-01-2019 15:06    04-01-2019  14  5
            4   04-01-2019 14:55    04-01-2019 15:06    04-01-2019  15  6
            22  04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32    04-01-2019  20  27
            22  04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32    04-01-2019  21  32
            22  04-01-2019 21:38    04-01-2019 21:42    04-01-2019  21  4
            25  04-01-2019 23:22    04-02-2019 00:23    04-01-2019  23  28
            25  04-01-2019 23:22    04-02-2019 00:23    04-02-2019  0   23
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  1   60
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  2   60
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  3   60
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  4   60
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  5   60
            29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15    04-02-2019  6   15
```

Code to create the dataframe:

```
data={'ID':[4,4,4,4,22,22,25,29],
  'checkin_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:07','04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 14:06','04-01-2019 14:55','04-01-2019 20:23'
  ,'04-01-2019 21:38','04-01-2019 23:22','04-02-2019 01:00'],
  'checkout_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 13:12','04-01-2019 14:07','04-01-2019 15:06','04-01-2019 21:32'
                       ,'04-01-2019 21:42','04-02-2019 00:23'
                       ,'04-02-2019 06:15']
}

df = DataFrame(data,columns= ['ID', 'checkin_datetime','checkout_datetime'])

df['checkout_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout_datetime'])
df['checkin_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkin_datetime'])
```

Comment: how do you calculate the hr and minutes column?

Comment: @JainilPatel   I have added on the code I used to create the data frame

Comment: @anky_91 the hr of the time time stamp: so in the example above for  22  04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32, the hour is 20 hours(8pm) and 27 minutes for that hour period and and then for the hour period 21 32 minutes , thats the split I need help in

Comment: @Ani how is `04-01-2019 20:23` minutes 27? shouldnt it be 23? do you want the difference between checkout and checkin?? please explain the calculation

Comment: @anky_91 My mistake while pasting the output I left out the 2nd line Which is now corrected  for the id 22  04-01-2019 20:23    04-01-2019 21:32 as its between 2 hours 8PM till 9PM is 27 minutes in the hour 20 and 32 minutes in the hour 21 (total of 59 minutes  split between the 2 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple: 
- for the duration, you just subtract the checkout from the checkin (`datetime` can do that). 
- To get it in minutes - divide it by a `timedelta` of one minute (I'll use the `pandas` built-in one). 
- to get the hour from a `datetime`, call `.hour`, and similarly `.date()` for the date (the first is an attribute, the second is a method - watch the parentheses).

```
df['Hour'] = df['checkin_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['Date'] = df['checkin_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df['duration'] = df['checkout_datetime']-df['checkin_datetime']
df['duration_in_minutes'] = (df['checkout_datetime']-df['checkin_datetime'])/pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
```

[Edited]: I have a solution to split the duration into hours, but it's not the most elegant...

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
    start=df['checkin_datetime'].min(),
    end=df['checkout_datetime'].max(),freq='1T'),
    columns = ['is_checked_in','ID'], data=0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df2['is_checked_in'][row['checkin_datetime']:row['checkout_datetime']] = 1
    df2['ID'][row['checkin_datetime']:row['checkout_datetime']] = row['ID']

df3 = df2.resample('1H').aggregate({'is_checked_in': sum,'ID':max})
df3['Hour'] = df3.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.hour)
```

Comment: This does not resolve the whole issue for the id 29 : 29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15 it give me this ID checkin_datetime    checkout_datetime Logged_time Hour Date  duration                     duration_in_minutes
   29 2019-04-02 01:00:00    2019-04-02 06:15:00 315.0       1 2019-04-02   0 days 05:15:00.000000000     315.0   That 315 minutes needs to be divided into multiple hours  right from 1 AM till 6:15 AM into 6 hourly buckets with the 1st 5 having 60 minutes and the last one with 15 minutes

Comment: how do I get this similar data with the ID and the hour and the date  involved ?

Comment: Very similarly (added to answer). The 'Hour' part is just an `.apply` like I've shown you before, and for the 'ID' we replace the `.sum()` with a more complex `.aggregate` that operates differently on each column (sum of ID will be a problem, but max of ID shouldn't be).

Comment: How do add another level to this  code, say something like zone_id to also to group the data ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Ask another question, with an example and explanation.

Comment: I have just posted the new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661066/dividing-time-intervals-with-multiple-index-into-hourly-buckets-in-python

Comment: Ah! Now I understand... just change the second-to-last row to `df2.groupby('Zone').resample('1H').aggregate({'is_checked_in': sum,'ID':max})`. Read more about `.groupby()`, it's very useful.

Comment: Ahha ok, so for the indexing I should  also add the zone as    df2['Zone'][row['checkin_datetime']:row['checkout_datetime']] = row['Zone']

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You can also set `data=np.nan` instead of `data=0` in the initialization of `df2`, this way you don't get a group with zone=0 (which isn't real).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data={'ID':[4,4,4,4,22,22,25,29],
  'checkin_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:07','04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 14:06','04-01-2019 14:55','04-01-2019 20:23'
  ,'04-01-2019 21:38','04-01-2019 23:22','04-02-2019 01:00'],
  'checkout_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 13:12','04-01-2019 14:07','04-01-2019 15:06','04-01-2019 21:32'
                       ,'04-01-2019 21:42','04-02-2019 00:23'
                       ,'04-02-2019 06:15']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['ID', 'checkin_datetime','checkout_datetime'])

df['checkout_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout_datetime'])
df['checkin_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkin_datetime'])
df['Hour'] = df['checkin_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.hour)
df['Date'] = df['checkin_datetime'].apply(lambda x: x.date())
df['duration'] = df['checkout_datetime']-df['checkin_datetime']
df['duration_in_minutes'] = (df['checkout_datetime']-df['checkin_datetime'])/pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    print(df)
```

i think previous answer given by Itamar Muskhkin is absolutely correct.

Comment: For the id 29  04-02-2019 01:00    04-02-2019 06:15 The above code gives me 1 line with the total logged in time at 1AM to 315 minutes. I need this 315 minutes split into the hourly buckets from 1 AM to 5 AM with  60 minutes in each bucket and the the 6 AM bucket with 15 minutes in it

Comment: so don't write 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 in hours. it resembles that hours passed.