# Dividing time intervals with multiple index into hourly buckets in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing

here is the code for the sample data set I have

```
data={'ID':[4,4,4,4,22,22,23,25,29],
      'Zone':[32,34,21,34,27,29,32,75,9],
  'checkin_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:07','04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 14:06','04-01-2019 14:55','04-01-2019 20:23'
  ,'04-01-2019 21:38','04-01-2019 21:38','04-01-2019 23:22','04-02-2019 01:00'],
  'checkout_datetime':['04-01-2019 13:09','04-01-2019 13:12','04-01-2019 14:07','04-01-2019 15:06','04-01-2019 21:32'
                       ,'04-01-2019 21:42','04-01-2019 21:45','04-02-2019 00:23','04-02-2019 06:15']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns= ['ID','Zone', 'checkin_datetime','checkout_datetime'])

df['checkout_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkout_datetime'])
df['checkin_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['checkin_datetime'])
```

Using this data set I am trying to create the following data set

```
                Checked_in_hour    ID    Zone    checked_in_minutes
                01-04-2019 13:00    4    32        2
                01-04-2019 13:00    4    34        3
                01-04-2019 14:00    4    21        1
                01-04-2019 14:00    4    34        5
                01-04-2019 15:00    4    34        6
                01-04-2019 20:00    22    27       37
                01-04-2019 20:00    22    27       8
                01-04-2019 20:00    22    27       37
                01-04-2019 21:00    22    29       4
                01-04-2019 21:00    23    32       7
                01-04-2019 23:00    25    75       38
                02-04-2019 00:00    25    75       24
                02-04-2019 01:00    29    9        60
                02-04-2019 02:00    29    9        60
                02-04-2019 03:00    29    9        60
                02-04-2019 04:00    29    9        60
                02-04-2019 05:00    29    9        60
                02-04-2019 06:00    29    9        16
```

Where Checked in hour is calculated by subtracting the checkin_datetime and the checkout_datetime and the time is grouped by hours and Zone

This is code I have so far which calculates this at Checked_in_hour level which I need to add on the Zone Variable

```
#working logic
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
index=pd.DatetimeIndex(
    start=df['checkin_datetime'].min(),
    end=df['checkout_datetime'].max(),freq='1T'),
    columns = ['is_checked_in','ID'], data=0)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df2['is_checked_in'][row['checkin_datetime']:row['checkout_datetime']] = 1
    df2['ID'][row['checkin_datetime']:row['checkout_datetime']] = row['ID']

df3 = df2.resample('1H').aggregate({'is_checked_in': sum,'ID':max})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is efficient, but should work.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import timedelta

def group_into_hourly_buckets(df):
    df['duration'] = df['checkout_datetime'] - df['checkin_datetime']
    grouped_data = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        dur = row['duration'].seconds//60
        start_time = row['checkin_datetime']
        hours_ = 0
        while dur > 0:
            _data = {}
            _data['Checked_in_hour'] = start_time.floor('H') + timedelta(hours=hours_)
            time_spent_in_window = min(dur, 60)
            if (hours_ == 0):
                time_spent_in_window = min(time_spent_in_window, ((start_time.ceil('H') - start_time).seconds)//60)
            _data['checked_in_minutes'] = time_spent_in_window
            _data['ID'] = row['ID']
            _data['Zone'] = row['Zone']
            dur -= time_spent_in_window
            hours_ += 1
            grouped_data.append(_data)
    return pd.DataFrame(grouped_data)
```

Comment: Also, in the example data set, why are there 3 rows with the same Checked_in_hour, ID and Zone?

Comment: this works great but I did find a sutvaiton that where the loop is not  
working  ID Zone checkin_datetime checkout_datetime
14774 252 2019-06-01 00:02:43 2019-06-01 01:00:29
14774 252 2019-06-01 01:51:12 2019-06-01 03:16:26
14774 252 2019-06-01 03:21:11 2019-06-01 03:55:15
14774 216 2019-06-01 03:55:15 2019-06-01 03:55:55
   
Checked_in_hour checked_in_minutes ID Zone
2019-06-01 01:00:00 8 14774 252
2019-06-01 02:00:00 60 14774 252
2019-06-01 03:00:00 17 14774 252
2019-06-01 03:00:00 34 14774 252
I this case  the ID 216 is being missed out in the loop

Comment: that was mistake while copying the data, apologies

Comment: @Ani that's because the `Checked_in_duration` for ID `216` is less than 1 minute

Comment: I need to capture that too, so how do I add on a decimal place to the minute ?

Comment: or is it possible to roundup any seconds that are less than a minute to the next upper minute?